# Google wallet merchant settings URL

Tags: android-pay

Sorry for the silly question but I cannot find the URL to get to google wallet merchant settings. I got an email saying I need to update tax info but I cant find the place to do so

Comment: Though some times we find no way other than posting question on SO.. still such questions are discouraged. Well said its silly :).

Answer (score 2):

Try https://wallet.google.com/merchant/, then click on Merchant Settings in left hand margin, then click on Tax Information at top menu line.